# What happens with AppDomain.CreateInstance() parameters?

Tags: c#

I am trying to find out what happens with each of the parameters in AppDomain for a specific override. After reading the docs, I have a general idea of what each one is, but I'm quite lost as to how each one affects the new instance that is created.

This is the override that I'm using. I am especially confused about what the Object[] parameters do.

```cs
CreateInstance(String, String, Boolean, BindingFlags, Binder, Object[], CultureInfo, Object[])
```

Comment: They pass the arguments that the constructor needs.

Comment: You can check [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/activator.cs,303)

Comment: Did you read the documentation?  That tells you how arguments are used.

Comment: I read the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_AppDomain_CreateInstance_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_System_Reflection_BindingFlags_System_Reflection_Binder_System_Object___System_Globalization_CultureInfo_System_Object___) but I'm not sure what 'constructor' is receiving the items in arg object[] and how they affect the AppDomain.

Comment: You are creating an instance of an object. (`Creates a new instance of the specified type defined in the specified assembly.`) When you do that, a constructor is invoked. Those arguments are passed to that constructor call, like the docs say.